# Service lifetime in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a simple question but didn't find an answer anywhere.

Solution contain two Web API. One is .NET Core 2.1 with EF Core 2.1.1 and the second is 3.1 with EF Core 3.1.1 and my code is the same for both. There are one custom repository and one controller.

Person repository:

```
public PersonRepository(AppContext appContext)
{
   this.appContext = appContext;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetAll()
{
    return await appContext.People.ToListAsync();
}
```

Controller:

```
public MyController(PersonRepository personRepository)
{
    this.personRepository = personRepository;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
    var data = personRepository.GetAll();
    var data1 = personRepository.GetAll();

    var result = await Task.WhenAll(data, data1);

    return Ok(data.Result);
}
```

```
services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => options
.UseSqlServer("")
.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true));
```

It might seem nonsense. But this is only for demonstration.
My question is, why this code **works** in 2.1 solution but in 3.1 **not** and exception appear
*InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.* (Same for IIS and Kestrel).

I know how to fix it in 3.1 this is not my question. I just need to know why this happened and what's changed between these versions or whenever.

Thank you very much for any response.

Comment: I don't believe that DbContext is thread safe in EF Core 2 or 3.  As such you shouldn't be running both `personRepository.GetAll()` tasks on the same context in `Task.WhenAll` as they _may_ run at the same time.
You should `async/await` each call in 2 and 3.
One of the issues with Task scheduling is you don't know how it will be done.  It's possible that in your 2 sample the two tasks are running sequentually and in your 3 sample they are running concurrently and giving you the error.

Comment: @GrahamKing Thank you for your comment. Yes, DBContext is not thread-safe. So it might be done as you say, that I don't know how it's done (Task scheduling). This is very interesting I need to look at it more deeply.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to run both queries in parallel you'd need two `DbContext`s because `DbContext` is not thread safe.

You need to change how you register the DbContext in your service container to do this:

```
 services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options
            .UseSqlServer("")
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true), 
            ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Add the ability for the depedency to create a new instance of the `DbContext` (a simple factory):

```
services.AddTransient<Func<AppDbContext>>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>);
```

and change your dependency accordingly:

```
public PersonRepository(Func<AppContext> appContextFactory)
{
    this.appContextFactory = appContextFactory;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetAll()
{
   using (var appContext = appContextFactory())
   {
       return await appContext.People.ToListAsync();
   }
}
```

Remember that changing the lifetime scope to `Transient` means that if you inject `DbContext` in multiple classes within the same request you will **not** get the same `DbContext` instance.  Use with caution.

Comment: Hello Mr. @GrahamKing My solution to get it works have exactly the same implementation as you suppose. My only question was why there is a difference between the two versions. Maybe as you said, "One of the issues with Task Scheduling is you don't know how it will be done. It's possible that in your 2 sample the two tasks are running sequentually and in your 3 sample they are running concurrently and giving you the error.". Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad you got it working @T.Dominik.
Maybe you could mark this as the answer if you found the above help.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers has some guidence on what to do when someone answers your question.

Comment: Hello @GrahamKing ... this actually not answers to my question. Because I knew this solution before you post your answer. As I said in my original question (I know how to get it to work ). I am very sorry for that